# Where can I buy Litecoin?

Tags: exchanges, litecoin

I know [Litecoin](http://litecoin.org/) is sold on [Coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/join/514b7813555892e90f0000bf), but I'm wondering if anyone has compiled a list or knows of other exchanges selling the currency?

Comment: Best to put that list as an answer rather than in the question.

Comment: If you are in Australia you can buy Litecoin on my exchange CoinSpot :D www.coinspot.com.au

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the list of [exchanges](http://litecoin.info/Service_Directory#Exchanges) currently selling Litecoin

- [Coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/join/514b7813555892e90f0000bf)
- [Bittrex](https://bittrex.com/)
- [Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/)
- [Bitfinex](https://www.bitfinex.com/)

Answer (score 15):

The most current list of Litecoin exchanges, originally from the Litecoin wiki, updated in December 2017 to remove nonfunctional exchanges:

> #### Market exchanges
>
> - [Kraken](https://www.kraken.com)
> - [The Rock Trading](https://www.therocktrading.com/en/exchange/currency)
> - [UpBit](https://upbit.com/) - Korean exchange
> - [Bithumb](https://bithumb.com/) - Korean exchange
> - [BTCTrade](http://www.btctrade.com/ltc/) - Chinese exchange
> - [OkCoin](http://www.okcoin.com) - Chinese exchange
>
> #### Fixed rate exchanges
>
> - [Okpay](https://www.okpay.com/)
> - [Litecoinlocal](https://www.litecoinlocal.net/)
> - [BitBargain](https://bitbargain.co.uk/buy?thing=LTC&pay_method=&by=amount&amount=/)
> - [24change](https://24change.com/)
> - [ALFAcashier](https://www.alfacashier.com/)
> - [GOLDUX](https://goldux.com/)

Comment: https://www.bitstamp.net - LTC/USD, LTC/EUR and LTC/BTC

Answer (score 11):

There is a list of exchanges (and other businesses and tools) in the Litecoin wiki: https://litecoin.info/Service_Directory#Market_exchanges

Answer (score 0):

There is a Norway exchange where you can buy and sell, it is called [Justcoin](https://justcoin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is also quite new, but interesting exchange https://www.247exchange.com/ allowing to buy litecoins with credit and debit cards, bank transfers and cash deposits (400k locations worldwide). That I liked most, that they do not hold user's funds and there is no need to trade there - they will fund your litecoin account right after you will make a payment. Although I was upset that they limit first credit card purchases with about $100, the rates are better than at most other exchanges and instant delivery works great!

Answer (score -1):

For the most updated list, take a look here:

http://exchangewar.info/coinprice?LTC_BTC

You can find those exchanges using fiat currency too. For example:

http://exchangewar.info/coinprice?LTC_USD

http://exchangewar.info/coinprice?LTC_EUR

http://exchangewar.info/coinprice?LTC_CNY

etc. ;)