# What is Buttercoin, and how does it differ from other exchanges such as Coinbase?

Tags: coinbase.com, buttercoin

I successfully purchased some Bitcoins via Coinbase. Coinbase makes sense to me as it seems like buying a stock like I can via ETrade. I was able to easily link my bank account to coinbase and it seemed very straightforward.

Earlier today, I stumbled up [Buttercoin](http://www.buttercoin.com/). It describes itself as a Bitcoin Exchange. Later, it mentions that I can link my bank account. How does Coinbase differ from Buttercoin? Or are they two similar but competing services?

Comment: -1 I might be misinterpreting your intent, but I got the feeling that this question's content could be condensed into "What is Buttercoin, and how does it differ from other exchanges such as Coinbase?". That would be a much better question. The part about Litecoin should be it's own question, but it has answers here already, see for example http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10447/where-can-i-buy-litecoin.

Comment: You are asking separate things that doesn't make sense together.

Answer (score -2):

Buttercoin is a work in progress, it is open-source driven and is kinda slow in its development right now.

Comment: This is answering only a small part of the question's scope, it would be nice if you elaborated on "how Buttercoin differs from other exchanges".

Comment: I've just told you how it differs. Other exchanges use their own code and matching engine (close source). The Litecoin question should not be there anyway.

Comment: Actually, I was getting at Buttercoin's failure to find a banking partner in the US, and that they are now offering their software as a service to multiple companies around the globe in exchange for a share of their revenue. So, it is an exchange software service, not an exchange.