# Buying Litecoins Directly

Tags: litecoin

Is it possible to buy litecoins directly with money from an institution like Mt.Gox without buying Bitcoins first and swapping them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BTC-e](https://btc-e.com) offers LTC/USD, LTC/EUR, and LTC/RUR pairs that enable the direct purchase of LTC.  However, depending on your location and the payment methods available to you, it may be easier and cheaper to buy BTC first and then exchange them for LTC.

Answer (score 1):

The following [exchanges](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/17091/1489) allow you to buy Litecoins directly:

- [Harborly](http://harbor.ly/)
- [Crypto-Trade](https://www.crypto-trade.com/trade/ltc_usd)
- [BTC-E](https://btc-e.com/exchange/ltc_usd)
- [UpBit](https://upbit.org/how-to-buy/)
- [OKCoin](https://www.okcoin.com/) (Chinese)
- [Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/)
- Or you could [find a local trader](https://www.litecoinlocal.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [expresscoin](http://expco.in/a8). we provide fast and easy way to buy litecoin and other digital currencies.